# LibreOffice Writer has strange characters in menus

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, language-support

I am using English language in Ubuntu, but I set Polish input.
I have a strange problem with displaying some text in menus in LibreOffice.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Output for: fc-match -a

> Blockquote
>   DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
>   DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Condensed"
>   DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "ExtraLight"
>   DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold"
>   DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Condensed Bold"
>   DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Oblique"
>   DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Condensed Oblique"
>   DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold Oblique"
>   DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Condensed Bold Oblique"
>   n019003l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular"
>   n019003l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular"
>   n019043l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular Condensed"
>   n019043l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular Condensed"
>   n019004l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold"
>   n019004l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold"
>   n019044l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold Condensed"
>   n019044l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold Condensed"
>   n019023l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular Italic"
>   n019023l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular Italic"
>   n019063l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular Condensed Italic"
>   n019063l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular Condensed Italic"
>   n019024l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold Italic"
>   n019024l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold Italic"
>   n019064l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold Condensed Italic"
>   n019064l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Bold Condensed Italic"
>   Waree.ttf: "Waree" "Regular"
>   Waree-Bold.ttf: "Waree" "Bold"
>   Waree-Oblique.ttf: "Waree" "Oblique"
>   Waree-BoldOblique.ttf: "Waree" "Bold Oblique"
>   Loma.ttf: "Loma" "Regular"
>   Loma-Bold.ttf: "Loma" "Bold"
>   Loma-Oblique.ttf: "Loma" "Oblique"
>   Loma-BoldOblique.ttf: "Loma" "Bold Oblique"
>   Garuda.ttf: "Garuda" "Regular"
>   Garuda-Bold.ttf: "Garuda" "Bold"
>   Garuda-Oblique.ttf: "Garuda" "Oblique"
>   Garuda-BoldOblique.ttf: "Garuda" "Bold Oblique"
>   Umpush.ttf: "Umpush" "Regular"
>   Umpush-Light.ttf: "Umpush" "Light"
>   Umpush-Bold.ttf: "Umpush" "Bold"
>   Umpush-Oblique.ttf: "Umpush" "Oblique"
>   Umpush-LightOblique.ttf: "Umpush" "Light Oblique"
>   Umpush-BoldOblique.ttf: "Umpush" "Bold Oblique"
>   Laksaman.ttf: "Laksaman" "Regular"
>   Laksaman-Bold.ttf: "Laksaman" "Bold"
>   Laksaman-Italic.ttf: "Laksaman" "Italic"
>   Laksaman-BoldItalic.ttf: "Laksaman" "Bold Italic"
>   NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK JP" "Regular"
>   NotoSansCJK-Medium.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK JP" "Medium"
>   NotoSansCJK-DemiLight.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK JP" "DemiLight"
>   NotoSansCJK-Light.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK JP" "Light"
>   NotoSansCJK-Thin.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK JP" "Thin"
>   NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK JP" "Bold"
>   NotoSansCJK-Black.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK JP" "Black"
>   NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK SC" "Regular"
>   NotoSansCJK-Medium.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK SC" "Medium"
>   NotoSansCJK-DemiLight.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK SC" "DemiLight"
>   NotoSansCJK-Light.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK SC" "Light"
>   NotoSansCJK-Thin.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK SC" "Thin"
>   NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK SC" "Bold"
>   NotoSansCJK-Black.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK SC" "Black"
>   NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK TC" "Regular"
>   NotoSansCJK-Medium.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK TC" "Medium"
>   NotoSansCJK-DemiLight.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK TC" "DemiLight"
>   NotoSansCJK-Light.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK TC" "Light"
>   NotoSansCJK-Thin.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK TC" "Thin"
>   NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK TC" "Bold"
>   NotoSansCJK-Black.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK TC" "Black"
>   KhmerOS.ttf: "Khmer OS" "Regular"
>   NanumGothic.ttf: "NanumGothic" "Regular"
>   NanumGothicBold.ttf: "NanumGothic" "Bold"
>   UnDotum.ttf: "UnDotum" "Regular"
>   UnDotumBold.ttf: "UnDotum" "Bold"
>   Lohit-Punjabi.ttf: "Lohit Punjabi" "Regular"
>   lklug.ttf: "LKLUG" "Regular"
>   wqy-microhei.ttc: "WenQuanYi Micro Hei" "Regular"
>   FreeSans.ttf: "FreeSans" "Regular"
>   FreeSansBold.ttf: "FreeSans" "Bold"
>   FreeSansOblique.ttf: "FreeSans" "Oblique"
>   FreeSansBoldOblique.ttf: "FreeSans" "Bold Oblique"
>   FreeMono.ttf: "FreeMono" "Regular"
>   FreeSerif.ttf: "FreeSerif" "Regular"
>   opens___.ttf: "OpenSymbol" "Regular"
>   ume-pgc4.ttf: "Ume P Gothic C4" "Regular"
>   ume-pgc5.ttf: "Ume P Gothic C5" "Medium"
>   ume-pgo4.ttf: "Ume P Gothic" "Regular"
>   ume-pgo5.ttf: "Ume P Gothic O5" "Medium"
>   ume-pgs4.ttf: "Ume P Gothic S4" "Regular"
>   ume-pgs5.ttf: "Ume P Gothic S5" "Medium"
>   ume-pmo3.ttf: "Ume P Mincho" "Regular"
>   ume-pms3.ttf: "Ume P Mincho S3" "Regular"
>   ume-tgc4.ttf: "Ume Gothic C4" "Regular"
>   ume-tgc5.ttf: "Ume Gothic C5" "Medium"
>   ume-tgo4.ttf: "Ume Gothic" "Regular"
>   ume-tgo5.ttf: "Ume Gothic O5" "Medium"
>   ume-tgs4.ttf: "Ume Gothic S4" "Regular"
>   ume-tgs5.ttf: "Ume Gothic S5" "Medium"
>   ume-tmo3.ttf: "Ume Mincho" "Regular"
>   ume-tms3.ttf: "Ume Mincho S3" "Regular"
>   ume-ugo4.ttf: "Ume UI Gothic" "Regular"
>   ume-ugo5.ttf: "Ume UI Gothic O5" "Medium"
>   Norasi.ttf: "Norasi" "Regular"
>   KacstOne.ttf: "KacstOne" "Regular"
>   fonts-japanese-gothic.ttf: "TakaoPGothic" "Regular"
>   TakaoPGothic.ttf: "TakaoPGothic" "Regular"
>   KhmerOSsys.ttf: "Khmer OS System" "Regular"
>   Purisa.ttf: "Purisa" "Regular"
>   Padauk-book.ttf: "Padauk Book" "Regular"
>   Padauk.ttf: "Padauk" "Regular"
>   DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
>   DejaVuSerif.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Book"
>   KacstQurn.ttf: "KacstQurn" "Medium"
>   KacstTitleL.ttf: "KacstTitleL" "Medium"
>   Lato-Regular.ttf: "Lato" "Regular"
>   Sawasdee.ttf: "Sawasdee" "Regular"
>   texgyreschola-regular.otf: "TeX Gyre Schola" "Regular"
>   lmmono10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Mono" "10 Regular"
>   lmmono12-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Mono" "12 Regular"
>   lmmono8-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Mono" "8 Regular"
>   lmmono9-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Mono" "9 Regular"
>   lmmonocaps10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Caps" "10 Regular"
>   lmmonolt10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Light" "10 Regular"
>   lmmonoltcond10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Light Cond" "10 Regular"
>   lmmonoprop10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Prop" "10 Regular"
>   lmmonoproplt10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Prop Light" "10 Regular"
>   lmmonoslant10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Slanted" "10 Regular"
>   lmroman10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "10 Regular"
>   lmroman12-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "12 Regular"
>   lmroman17-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "17 Regular"
>   lmroman5-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "5 Regular"
>   lmroman6-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "6 Regular"
>   lmroman7-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "7 Regular"
>   lmroman8-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "8 Regular"
>   lmroman9-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "9 Regular"
>   lmromancaps10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Caps" "10 Regular"
>   lmromandunh10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Dunhill" "10 Regular"
>   lmromanslant10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Slanted" "10 Regular"
>   lmromanslant12-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Slanted" "12 Regular"
>   lmromanslant17-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Slanted" "17 Regular"
>   lmromanslant8-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Slanted" "8 Regular"
>   lmromanslant9-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Slanted" "9 Regular"
>   lmromanunsl10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Unslanted" "10 Regular"
>   lmsans10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "10 Regular"
>   lmsans12-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "12 Regular"
>   lmsans17-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "17 Regular"
>   lmsans8-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "8 Regular"
>   lmsans9-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "9 Regular"
>   lmsansquot8-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Sans Quotation" "8 Regular"
>   texgyrebonum-regular.otf: "TeX Gyre Bonum" "Regular"
>   texgyrecursor-regular.otf: "TeX Gyre Cursor" "Regular"
>   texgyreheros-regular.otf: "TeX Gyre Heros" "Regular"
>   texgyrepagella-regular.otf: "TeX Gyre Pagella" "Regular"
>   texgyretermes-regular.otf: "TeX Gyre Termes" "Regular"
>   NanumMyeongjo.ttf: "NanumMyeongjo" "Regular"
>   texgyreadventor-regular.otf: "TeX Gyre Adventor" "Regular"
>   latinmodern-math.otf: "Latin Modern Math" "Regular"
>   TibetanMachineUni.ttf: "Tibetan Machine Uni" "Regular"
>   texgyrepagella-math.otf: "TeX Gyre Pagella Math" "Regular"
>   texgyretermes-math.otf: "TeX Gyre Termes Math" "Regular"
>   texgyreschola-math.otf: "TeX Gyre Schola Math" "Regular"
>   AbyssinicaSIL-R.ttf: "Abyssinica SIL" "Regular"
>   STIXGeneral-Regular.otf: "STIXGeneral" "Regular"
>   STIX-Regular.otf: "STIX" "Regular"
>   STIXMath-Regular.otf: "STIX Math" "Regular"
>   STIXIntegralsD-Regular.otf: "STIXIntegralsD" "Regular"
>   STIXIntegralsSm-Regular.otf: "STIXIntegralsSm" "Regular"
>   STIXIntegralsUp-Regular.otf: "STIXIntegralsUp" "Regular"
>   STIXIntegralsUpD-Regular.otf: "STIXIntegralsUpD" "Regular"
>   STIXIntegralsUpSm-Regular.otf: "STIXIntegralsUpSm" "Regular"
>   STIXNonUnicode-Regular.otf: "STIXNonUnicode" "Regular"
>   STIXSizeFiveSym-Regular.otf: "STIXSizeFiveSym" "Regular"
>   STIXSizeFourSym-Regular.otf: "STIXSizeFourSym" "Regular"
>   STIXSizeOneSym-Regular.otf: "STIXSizeOneSym" "Regular"
>   STIXSizeThreeSym-Regular.otf: "STIXSizeThreeSym" "Regular"
>   STIXSizeTwoSym-Regular.otf: "STIXSizeTwoSym" "Regular"
>   STIXVariants-Regular.otf: "STIXVariants" "Regular"
>   LiberationMono-Regular.ttf: "Liberation Mono" "Regular"
>   LiberationSans-Regular.ttf: "Liberation Sans" "Regular"
>   LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf: "Liberation Serif" "Regular"
>   texgyrebonum-math.otf: "TeX Gyre Bonum Math" "Regular"
>   NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK KR" "Regular"
>   NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Sans Mono CJK JP" "Regular"
>   NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Sans Mono CJK KR" "Regular"
>   NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Sans Mono CJK SC" "Regular"
>   NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Sans Mono CJK TC" "Regular"
>   mry_KacstQurn.ttf: "mry_KacstQurn" "Regular"
>   Phetsarath_OT.ttf: "Phetsarath OT" "Regular"
>   UnDinaru.ttf: "UnDinaru" "Regular"
>   NanumBarunGothic.ttf: "NanumBarunGothic" "Regular"
>   Ubuntu-C.ttf: "Ubuntu Condensed" "Regular"
>   Ubuntu-R.ttf: "Ubuntu" "Regular"
>   UbuntuMono-R.ttf: "Ubuntu Mono" "Regular"
>   wqy-microhei.ttc: "WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono" "Regular"
>   Saab.ttf: "Saab" "Regular"
>   b018012l.pfb: "URW Bookman L" "Light"
>   c0419bt_.pfb: "Courier 10 Pitch" "Regular"
>   c0648bt_.pfb: "Bitstream Charter" "Regular"
>   n021003l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Regular"
>   n022003l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Regular"
>   UnBatang.ttf: "UnBatang" "Regular"
>   UnGraphic.ttf: "UnGraphic" "Regular"
>   UnGungseo.ttf: "UnGungseo" "Regular"
>   UnPilgi.ttf: "UnPilgi" "Regular"
>   b018012l.pfb: "URW Bookman L" "Light"
>   n021003l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Regular"
>   n022003l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Regular"
>   bchr8a.pfb: "Bitstream Charter" "Regular"
>   pcrr8a.pfb: "Courier" "Regular"
>   putr8a.pfb: "Utopia" "Regular"
>   d050000l.pfb: "Dingbats" "Regular"
>   s050000l.pfb: "Standard Symbols L" "Regular"
>   d050000l.pfb: "Dingbats" "Regular"
>   s050000l.pfb: "Standard Symbols L" "Regular"
>   Symbola_hint.ttf: "Symbola" "Regular"
>   DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Condensed"
>   texgyreheroscn-regular.otf: "TeX Gyre Heros Cn" "Regular"
>   LiberationSansNarrow-Regular.ttf: "Liberation Sans Narrow" "Regular"
>   a010013l.pfb: "URW Gothic L" "Book"
>   a010013l.pfb: "URW Gothic L" "Book"
>   TlwgTypo.ttf: "Tlwg Typo" "Regular"
>   KacstArt.ttf: "KacstArt" "Medium"
>   KacstBook.ttf: "KacstBook" "Medium"
>   KacstDecorative.ttf: "KacstDecorative" "Medium"
>   KacstDigital.ttf: "KacstDigital" "Medium"
>   KacstFarsi.ttf: "KacstFarsi" "Medium"
>   KacstLetter.ttf: "KacstLetter" "Medium"
>   KacstNaskh.ttf: "KacstNaskh" "Medium"
>   KacstOffice.ttf: "KacstOffice" "Medium"
>   KacstPen.ttf: "KacstPen" "Medium"
>   KacstPoster.ttf: "KacstPoster" "Medium"
>   KacstScreen.ttf: "KacstScreen" "Medium"
>   KacstTitle.ttf: "KacstTitle" "Medium"
>   TlwgTypist.ttf: "Tlwg Typist" "Regular"
>   Kinnari.ttf: "Kinnari" "Regular"
>   TlwgTypewriter.ttf: "Tlwg Typewriter" "Regular"
>   Lato-Medium.ttf: "Lato" "Medium"
>   texgyrechorus-mediumitalic.otf: "TeX Gyre Chorus" "Regular"
>   TlwgMono.ttf: "Tlwg Mono" "Regular"
>   NotoSansCJK-Medium.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK KR" "Medium"
>   Ubuntu-M.ttf: "Ubuntu" "Medium"
>   c059013l.pfb: "Century Schoolbook L" "Roman"
>   p052003l.pfb: "URW Palladio L" "Roman"
>   c059013l.pfb: "Century Schoolbook L" "Roman"
>   p052003l.pfb: "URW Palladio L" "Roman"
>   NotoSansCJK-DemiLight.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK KR" "DemiLight"
>   Lato-Light.ttf: "Lato" "Light"
>   NotoSansCJK-Light.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK KR" "Light"
>   UnDinaruLight.ttf: "UnDinaru" "Light"
>   Ubuntu-L.ttf: "Ubuntu" "Light"
>   NotoSansCJK-Thin.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK KR" "Thin"
>   Lato-Thin.ttf: "Lato" "Thin"
>   Lato-Hairline.ttf: "Lato" "Hairline"
>   Lato-Semibold.ttf: "Lato" "Semibold"
>   lmromandemi10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Demi" "10 Regular"
>   lmsansdemicond10-regular.otf: "Latin Modern Sans Demi Cond" "10 Regular"
>   a010015l.pfb: "URW Gothic L" "Demi"
>   a010015l.pfb: "URW Gothic L" "Demi"
>   FreeSerifBold.ttf: "FreeSerif" "Bold"
>   FreeMonoBold.ttf: "FreeMono" "Bold"
>   Norasi-Bold.ttf: "Norasi" "Bold"
>   KacstOne-Bold.ttf: "KacstOne" "Bold"
>   TlwgTypo-Bold.ttf: "Tlwg Typo" "Bold"
>   Purisa-Bold.ttf: "Purisa" "Bold"
>   Padauk-bold.ttf: "Padauk" "Bold"
>   Padauk-bookbold.ttf: "Padauk Book" "Bold"
>   DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Bold"
>   DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Bold"
>   TlwgTypist-Bold.ttf: "Tlwg Typist" "Bold"
>   Lato-Bold.ttf: "Lato" "Bold"
>   Kinnari-Bold.ttf: "Kinnari" "Bold"
>   Sawasdee-Bold.ttf: "Sawasdee" "Bold"
>   TlwgTypewriter-Bold.ttf: "Tlwg Typewriter" "Bold"
>   texgyreschola-bold.otf: "TeX Gyre Schola" "Bold"
>   lmmonolt10-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Light" "10 Bold"
>   lmmonoproplt10-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Prop Light" "10 Bold"
>   lmroman10-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "10 Bold"
>   lmroman12-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "12 Bold"
>   lmroman5-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "5 Bold"
>   lmroman6-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "6 Bold"
>   lmroman7-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "7 Bold"
>   lmroman8-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "8 Bold"
>   lmroman9-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "9 Bold"
>   lmromanslant10-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Slanted" "10 Bold"
>   lmsans10-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "10 Bold"
>   lmsansquot8-bold.otf: "Latin Modern Sans Quotation" "8 Bold"
>   texgyrebonum-bold.otf: "TeX Gyre Bonum" "Bold"
>   texgyrecursor-bold.otf: "TeX Gyre Cursor" "Bold"
>   texgyreheros-bold.otf: "TeX Gyre Heros" "Bold"
>   texgyrepagella-bold.otf: "TeX Gyre Pagella" "Bold"
>   texgyretermes-bold.otf: "TeX Gyre Termes" "Bold"
>   texgyreadventor-bold.otf: "TeX Gyre Adventor" "Bold"
>   STIXGeneral-Bold.otf: "STIXGeneral" "Bold"
>   STIX-Bold.otf: "STIX" "Bold"
>   STIXIntegralsD-Bold.otf: "STIXIntegralsD" "Bold"
>   STIXIntegralsSm-Bold.otf: "STIXIntegralsSm" "Bold"
>   STIXIntegralsUp-Bold.otf: "STIXIntegralsUp" "Bold"
>   STIXIntegralsUpD-Bold.otf: "STIXIntegralsUpD" "Bold"
>   STIXIntegralsUpSm-Bold.otf: "STIXIntegralsUpSm" "Bold"
>   STIXNonUnicode-Bold.otf: "STIXNonUnicode" "Bold"
>   STIXSizeFourSym-Bold.otf: "STIXSizeFourSym" "Bold"
>   STIXSizeOneSym-Bold.otf: "STIXSizeOneSym" "Bold"
>   STIXSizeThreeSym-Bold.otf: "STIXSizeThreeSym" "Bold"
>   STIXSizeTwoSym-Bold.otf: "STIXSizeTwoSym" "Bold"
>   STIXVariants-Bold.otf: "STIXVariants" "Bold"
>   LiberationMono-Bold.ttf: "Liberation Mono" "Bold"
>   LiberationSans-Bold.ttf: "Liberation Sans" "Bold"
>   LiberationSerif-Bold.ttf: "Liberation Serif" "Bold"
>   TlwgMono-Bold.ttf: "Tlwg Mono" "Bold"
>   NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK KR" "Bold"
>   NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc: "Noto Sans Mono CJK JP" "Bold"
>   NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc: "Noto Sans Mono CJK KR" "Bold"
>   NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc: "Noto Sans Mono CJK SC" "Bold"
>   NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc: "Noto Sans Mono CJK TC" "Bold"
>   UnDinaruBold.ttf: "UnDinaru" "Bold"
>   NanumBarunGothicBold.ttf: "NanumBarunGothic" "Bold"
>   NanumMyeongjoBold.ttf: "NanumMyeongjo" "Bold"
>   Ubuntu-B.ttf: "Ubuntu" "Bold"
>   UbuntuMono-B.ttf: "Ubuntu Mono" "Bold"
>   b018015l.pfb: "URW Bookman L" "Demi Bold"
>   c0583bt_.pfb: "Courier 10 Pitch" "Bold"
>   c059016l.pfb: "Century Schoolbook L" "Bold"
>   c0632bt_.pfb: "Bitstream Charter" "Bold"
>   n021004l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Medium"
>   n022004l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Bold"
>   p052004l.pfb: "URW Palladio L" "Bold"
>   UnBatangBold.ttf: "UnBatang" "Bold"
>   UnGraphicBold.ttf: "UnGraphic" "Bold"
>   UnPilgiBold.ttf: "UnPilgi" "Bold"
>   b018015l.pfb: "URW Bookman L" "Demi Bold"
>   c059016l.pfb: "Century Schoolbook L" "Bold"
>   n021004l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Medium"
>   n022004l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Bold"
>   p052004l.pfb: "URW Palladio L" "Bold"
>   bchb8a.pfb: "Bitstream Charter" "Bold"
>   pcrb8a.pfb: "Courier" "Bold"
>   putb8a.pfb: "Utopia" "Bold"
>   DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Condensed Bold"
>   texgyreheroscn-bold.otf: "TeX Gyre Heros Cn" "Bold"
>   LiberationSansNarrow-Bold.ttf: "Liberation Sans Narrow" "Bold"
>   Lato-Heavy.ttf: "Lato" "Heavy"
>   Lato-Black.ttf: "Lato" "Black"
>   NotoSansCJK-Black.ttc: "Noto Sans CJK KR" "Black"
>   FreeSerifItalic.ttf: "FreeSerif" "Italic"
>   FreeMonoOblique.ttf: "FreeMono" "Oblique"
>   Norasi-Italic.ttf: "Norasi" "Italic"
>   DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Italic"
>   Lato-Italic.ttf: "Lato" "Italic"
>   texgyreschola-italic.otf: "TeX Gyre Schola" "Italic"
>   lmmono10-italic.otf: "Latin Modern Mono" "10 Italic"
>   lmroman10-italic.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "10 Italic"
>   lmroman12-italic.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "12 Italic"
>   lmroman7-italic.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "7 Italic"
>   lmroman8-italic.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "8 Italic"
>   lmroman9-italic.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "9 Italic"
>   texgyrebonum-italic.otf: "TeX Gyre Bonum" "Italic"
>   texgyrecursor-italic.otf: "TeX Gyre Cursor" "Italic"
>   texgyreheros-italic.otf: "TeX Gyre Heros" "Italic"
>   texgyrepagella-italic.otf: "TeX Gyre Pagella" "Italic"
>   texgyretermes-italic.otf: "TeX Gyre Termes" "Italic"
>   texgyreadventor-italic.otf: "TeX Gyre Adventor" "Italic"
>   STIXGeneral-Italic.otf: "STIXGeneral" "Italic"
>   STIX-Italic.otf: "STIX" "Italic"
>   STIXNonUnicode-Italic.otf: "STIXNonUnicode" "Italic"
>   LiberationMono-Italic.ttf: "Liberation Mono" "Italic"
>   LiberationSans-Italic.ttf: "Liberation Sans" "Italic"
>   LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf: "Liberation Serif" "Italic"
>   Ubuntu-RI.ttf: "Ubuntu" "Italic"
>   UbuntuMono-RI.ttf: "Ubuntu Mono" "Italic"
>   b018032l.pfb: "URW Bookman L" "Light Italic"
>   c0582bt_.pfb: "Courier 10 Pitch" "Italic"
>   c059033l.pfb: "Century Schoolbook L" "Italic"
>   c0649bt_.pfb: "Bitstream Charter" "Italic"
>   n021023l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Regular Italic"
>   p052023l.pfb: "URW Palladio L" "Italic"
>   b018032l.pfb: "URW Bookman L" "Light Italic"
>   c059033l.pfb: "Century Schoolbook L" "Italic"
>   n021023l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Regular Italic"
>   p052023l.pfb: "URW Palladio L" "Italic"
>   bchri8a.pfb: "Bitstream Charter" "Italic"
>   pcrro8a.pfb: "Courier" "Italic"
>   putri8a.pfb: "Utopia" "Italic"
>   DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Condensed Italic"
>   texgyreheroscn-italic.otf: "TeX Gyre Heros Cn" "Italic"
>   LiberationSansNarrow-Italic.ttf: "Liberation Sans Narrow" "Italic"
>   Kinnari-Italic.ttf: "Kinnari" "Italic"
>   Lato-MediumItalic.ttf: "Lato" "Medium Italic"
>   Ubuntu-MI.ttf: "Ubuntu" "Medium Italic"
>   z003034l.pfb: "URW Chancery L" "Medium Italic"
>   z003034l.pfb: "URW Chancery L" "Medium Italic"
>   Lato-LightItalic.ttf: "Lato" "Light Italic"
>   Ubuntu-LI.ttf: "Ubuntu" "Light Italic"
>   Lato-ThinItalic.ttf: "Lato" "Thin Italic"
>   Lato-HairlineItalic.ttf: "Lato" "Hairline Italic"
>   Lato-SemiboldItalic.ttf: "Lato" "Semibold Italic"
>   FreeSerifBoldItalic.ttf: "FreeSerif" "Bold Italic"
>   FreeMonoBoldOblique.ttf: "FreeMono" "Bold Oblique"
>   Norasi-BoldItalic.ttf: "Norasi" "Bold Italic"
>   DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Bold Italic"
>   Lato-BoldItalic.ttf: "Lato" "Bold Italic"
>   Kinnari-BoldItalic.ttf: "Kinnari" "Bold Italic"
>   texgyreschola-bolditalic.otf: "TeX Gyre Schola" "Bold Italic"
>   lmroman10-bolditalic.otf: "Latin Modern Roman" "10 Bold Italic"
>   texgyrebonum-bolditalic.otf: "TeX Gyre Bonum" "Bold Italic"
>   texgyrecursor-bolditalic.otf: "TeX Gyre Cursor" "Bold Italic"
>   texgyreheros-bolditalic.otf: "TeX Gyre Heros" "Bold Italic"
>   texgyrepagella-bolditalic.otf: "TeX Gyre Pagella" "Bold Italic"
>   texgyretermes-bolditalic.otf: "TeX Gyre Termes" "Bold Italic"
>   texgyreadventor-bolditalic.otf: "TeX Gyre Adventor" "Bold Italic"
>   STIXGeneral-BoldItalic.otf: "STIXGeneral" "Bold Italic"
>   STIX-BoldItalic.otf: "STIX" "Bold Italic"
>   STIXNonUnicode-BoldItalic.otf: "STIXNonUnicode" "Bold Italic"
>   LiberationMono-BoldItalic.ttf: "Liberation Mono" "Bold Italic"
>   LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf: "Liberation Sans" "Bold Italic"
>   LiberationSerif-BoldItalic.ttf: "Liberation Serif" "Bold Italic"
>   Ubuntu-BI.ttf: "Ubuntu" "Bold Italic"
>   UbuntuMono-BI.ttf: "Ubuntu Mono" "Bold Italic"
>   b018035l.pfb: "URW Bookman L" "Demi Bold Italic"
>   c059036l.pfb: "Century Schoolbook L" "Bold Italic"
>   c0611bt_.pfb: "Courier 10 Pitch" "Bold Italic"
>   c0633bt_.pfb: "Bitstream Charter" "Bold Italic"
>   n021024l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Medium Italic"
>   p052024l.pfb: "URW Palladio L" "Bold Italic"
>   b018035l.pfb: "URW Bookman L" "Demi Bold Italic"
>   c059036l.pfb: "Century Schoolbook L" "Bold Italic"
>   n021024l.pfb: "Nimbus Roman No9 L" "Medium Italic"
>   p052024l.pfb: "URW Palladio L" "Bold Italic"
>   bchbi8a.pfb: "Bitstream Charter" "Bold Italic"
>   pcrbo8a.pfb: "Courier" "Bold Italic"
>   putbi8a.pfb: "Utopia" "Bold Italic"
>   DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Condensed Bold Italic"
>   texgyreheroscn-bolditalic.otf: "TeX Gyre Heros Cn" "Bold Italic"
>   LiberationSansNarrow-BoldItalic.ttf: "Liberation Sans Narrow" "Bold Italic"
>   Lato-HeavyItalic.ttf: "Lato" "Heavy Italic"
>   Lato-BlackItalic.ttf: "Lato" "Black Italic"
>   Norasi-Oblique.ttf: "Norasi" "Oblique"
>   Purisa-Oblique.ttf: "Purisa" "Oblique"
>   DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Oblique"
>   Sawasdee-Oblique.ttf: "Sawasdee" "Oblique"
>   TlwgTypewriter-Oblique.ttf: "Tlwg Typewriter" "Oblique"
>   lmmonocaps10-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Caps" "10 Oblique"
>   lmmonolt10-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Light" "10 Oblique"
>   lmmonoltcond10-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Light Cond" "10 Oblique"
>   lmmonoprop10-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Prop" "10 Oblique"
>   lmmonoproplt10-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Prop Light" "10 Oblique"
>   lmromancaps10-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Caps" "10 Oblique"
>   lmromandunh10-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Dunhill" "10 Oblique"
>   lmsans10-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "10 Oblique"
>   lmsans12-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "12 Oblique"
>   lmsans17-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "17 Oblique"
>   lmsans8-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "8 Oblique"
>   lmsans9-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "9 Oblique"
>   lmsansquot8-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Sans Quotation" "8 Oblique"
>   TlwgMono-Oblique.ttf: "Tlwg Mono" "Oblique"
>   n022023l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Regular Oblique"
>   n022023l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Regular Oblique"
>   a010033l.pfb: "URW Gothic L" "Book Oblique"
>   a010033l.pfb: "URW Gothic L" "Book Oblique"
>   TlwgTypo-Oblique.ttf: "Tlwg Typo" "Oblique"
>   TlwgTypist-Oblique.ttf: "Tlwg Typist" "Oblique"
>   Kinnari-Oblique.ttf: "Kinnari" "Oblique"
>   lmromandemi10-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Roman Demi" "10 Oblique"
>   lmsansdemicond10-oblique.otf: "Latin Modern Sans Demi Cond" "10 Oblique"
>   a010035l.pfb: "URW Gothic L" "Demi Oblique"
>   a010035l.pfb: "URW Gothic L" "Demi Oblique"
>   Norasi-BoldOblique.ttf: "Norasi" "Bold Oblique"
>   TlwgTypo-BoldOblique.ttf: "Tlwg Typo" "Bold Oblique"
>   Purisa-BoldOblique.ttf: "Purisa" "Bold Oblique"
>   DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Bold Oblique"
>   TlwgTypist-BoldOblique.ttf: "Tlwg Typist" "Bold Oblique"
>   Kinnari-BoldOblique.ttf: "Kinnari" "Bold Oblique"
>   Sawasdee-BoldOblique.ttf: "Sawasdee" "Bold Oblique"
>   TlwgTypewriter-BoldOblique.ttf: "Tlwg Typewriter" "Bold Oblique"
>   lmmonolt10-boldoblique.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Light" "10 Bold Oblique"
>   lmmonoproplt10-boldoblique.otf: "Latin Modern Mono Prop Light" "10 BoldOblique"
>   lmsans10-boldoblique.otf: "Latin Modern Sans" "10 Bold Oblique"
>   lmsansquot8-boldoblique.otf: "Latin Modern Sans Quotation" "8 Bold Oblique"
>   TlwgMono-BoldOblique.ttf: "Tlwg Mono" "Bold Oblique"
>   n022024l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Bold Oblique"
>   n022024l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Bold Oblique"

Comment: The input language is irrelevant. Have you installed and/or uninstalled any fonts?

Comment: Hmm really, I don't remember, because I have this problem for months and now I decided to repair this. How can I list all fonts?

Comment: The command `fc-match -a` will list all installed fonts. It's not easy to help, though,  if you are not able to tell us what you did.

Comment: I reinstalled LibreOffice and now it works.